# Can't copy files to Windows share with write-only / view-contents permissions

Tags: server, permissions, kubuntu, samba

I'm using Kubuntu 15.10. There is a share on a remote server that acts as a dropbox for my professors. Of course they don't want people copying or things from there. The Windows Permissions are set to allow me to "Create Files / Write Data" and "List Directory Contents".

So, when I copy something on there using Dolphin, the operation fails because Dolphin cannot rename the .part file on the server after copying it over. When using cp through the console, it simply tells me that the file or directory doesn't exist on the share.

Is there any way to copy without using a .part file? Is there a different file manager that can do that job?

Comment: If i am not wrong .part file is something work in progress(when somewhat bigger file is getting copied)...so you should wait for the entire file to be copied first.

Comment: I'm not trying to manually rename the .part file. This issue occurs with any file, not just large ones. To test this theory, I tried uploading a 1b text file. Same error.